# Spring Roo JPA - Why are manual DB updates automatically available in Persistence Context?

Tags: java, hibernate, sql-server-2005, jpa, spring-roo

I have developed a web app using Spring Roo (Spring MVC 3), JPA 1, Hibernate, JSTL, JQUERY etc..Persistence Contexts are application managed via a JPA Transaction manager. DB used is MSSQL2005. The application is running on JBOSS 5.

Everything works fine. My question is something that has been on my mind, yet i have yet to come across a suitable answer.

Suppose the following:

1. I retrieve some row from Table T using entitymanager.find(), and present the data to a page
2. I manually change one of the field values in the row (via SQL an gui tool).
3. I immediately repeat step (1), and I have the manually updated value available.

Is this correct? My understanding was that values within the persistence context do not get updated unless:

- calling em.refesh()
- object is not available in PERSISTENCE CONTEXT (--> query DB instead)

My experience seems to contradict the link below, which actually makes logical sense to me.

[Updated data (in Database) is not visible via JPA/Eclipselink](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7175044/updated-data-in-database-is-not-visible-via-jpa-eclipselink)

Many thanks

NaP

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the correct behavior. The values within a persistence context won't be updated unless you call em.refresh() within a SESSION. 
When you retrieve the web page again, the old session is closed and a new session is opened with new data reflected.